# Adding unit-tests for extracted methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

Let's say you're developing a product using TDD. You incrementally add tests and end up with a big method. Now it's time to refactor, so you separate the method in smaller methods. For example;

```
// Before refactoring.
public void SomeMethod()
{
    // ...
    int sum = numbers.Sum();
    // ...
}

// After refactoring.
public void SomeMethod()
{
    // ...
    int sum = GetSumOfNumbers(numbers);
    // ...
}

private GetSumOfNumbers(int[] numbers)
{
    return numbers.Sum();
}
```

After this step, should you write tests for the `GetSumOfNumbers` method? I think when we test `SomeMethod`, we already test `GetSumOfNumbers`. But at the same time, there may be other methods using `GetSumOfNumbers` and even though it works well for `SomeMethod`, it may not for another one. This would help us find the problem faster (as tests will give a more specific error). But at the same time, maybe this is not useful, and adds verbosity.

What do you think about it? And in the example, the `GetSumOfNumbers` method is private, so if you think it shouldn't be tested just because it's private, should it be tested if it's public?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should test the public API of your classes. Don't test the private methods. Doing so, will create a test suite that is coupled too tightly to your classes. Every internal change in your class would break some tests in your test suite.

If you think you should test a specific private method - maybe because it performs some complex or complicated logic - that's a smell telling you that it might be time to move that method into a new class.

Comment: +1. I like the suggestion of moving it out.

Comment: As I've mentioned in the end of my question, what if I decide that the method should be public in the end, and make it public. Should I write tests for that method?

Comment: @hattenn: Sure, see the first sentence of my answer: "You should test the public API of your classes". If you make that method public, it becomes part of the public API.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't.

The idea is that, as you're extracting methods, the tests cover your back. You can't test private methods (without reflection) anyway.

By testing methods that call `GetSumOfNumbers`, you're automatically testing it. Test coverage tools will confirm this.

Comment: A word about coverage: Only because a method is called by another method it does not mean that the method is covered complety. There are different ways to measure coverage. E.G. if you want some path coverage and have a switch in the private method only one call will not test it. (or if you have something like 'if(numbers!=null&& numbers.Count>0){...}else {return null or throw sth.}' you have a large chance that you never reach the  part with null if your programm is written correctly, and you only have conditions for error cases (somebody else changes the class and makes a wrong call).

Comment: I would aggree that these other public methods which were also put in the class later needs to be unit tested. But only because some method is calling another one, the other one is not covered completly!

Comment: Fair point. I didn't feel the need to mention that case.. perhaps I should have? :)

Comment: @Offler: That's why you want code coverage based on lines, not on methods. In your examples, you simply wouldn't have complete coverage of the method. Only a part would be covered. Having said that, I still agree that it sometimes is a problem - namely in cases when one lines has multiple statements / relevant parts.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Which is why tools that have the little green "code is covered" highlight next to line numbers are awesome. They are useful for seeing the paths in a method at a glance.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Even a line coverage does not tell much. I have a problem with translating this part. If you look at the graph ( http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e5/Teststrategien.svg ) the line coverage is the lowest coverage criteria. (i think roughly translated 'line cov < branch cov < path cov), while the other tree are stronger for structural coverage like decision and multi decision coverage). Maybe there are better translations in english ISTQB.

Comment: @Offler: I am German, so no problem here. As I said, I agree that even line coverage isn't always enough. But IMHO, most of the time, it is, because your code becomes unreadable, if you put too much into one line. But: I actually think that line coverage isn't something you should concentrate on. It is nice to see 100% line coverage, but it doesn't mean you actually tested the complete logic. What you *should* do is to test the "features" of a method or class. If you have tested all features, you will have a code coverage of 100% as a by-product.

Answer (score 1):

I'm tempted to conclude that you are half way there in your process of making your design more testable. Note that it by no means is "always better" to have more public methods / create a class for pretty much every private method.

The normal approach I follow while refactoring is exactly the same as you are taking:

- **apply refactoring "extract method" on long methods (1)**.

*When you are done doing that, you should be able to distinguish new objects from your tiny public method that just delegates the work to private methods.*

- **Apply the refactoring "introduce class for private method" (2)**.

*If it makes sense in your design/architecture! Use dependency injection to pass the object reference to your SuT (subject under test) so that you can mock it's behaviour. After that you can write new tests for the to-be-create class that represents your former private method.*

One thing I'd like to add. I believe that it's a bad practice promoting private methods to public methods "just because you wan't to write a test for it". I also think it's a bad practice to promote methods from private to internal, just to test them. I'll go one step to far: I think it's a bad practice to allow test projects to access internal methods. To me, that's all an indication of a design flaw. Doesn't mean that that's the reason to not do it. You can add a code smell in your code, as long as it is a conscious choice! In all other cases: keep your design testable, so that you don't have to cheat and promote private methods to public methods.

a perhaps too simple example:

```
public class TheThing
{
    private readonly ISummator _summator;

    public TheThing(ISummator summator)
    {
        _summator = summator;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        _summator.SumStuff();
    }
}
```